# Custom multivariate Dirichlet priors in pymc3

Tags: pymc3

Is it possible create custom multivariate distributions in pymc3? In the following, I have tried to create a linear transformation of a Dirichlet distribution. All variants on this have returned numerous errors, perhaps to do with theano data types? Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pymc
import theano.tensor as tt


# data
n = 5
prior_params = np.ones(n - 1) / (n - 1)
mx = np.array([[0.25 , 0.5  , 0.75 , 1.   ],    
              [0.25 , 0.333, 0.25 , 0.   ],
              [0.25 , 0.167, 0.   , 0.   ],
              [0.25 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ]])
# Note that the matrix mx takes the unit simplex into the unit simplex.

# custom log-liklihood
def generate_function(mx, prior_params):
    def log_trunc_dir(x):
        return pymc.Dirichlet.dist(a=prior_params).logp(mx.dot(x.T)).eval()
    return log_trunc_dir

#model
with pymc.Model() as simple_model:
    x = pymc.Dirichlet('x', a=np.ones(n - 1))
    q = pymc.DensityDist('q', generate_function(mx, prior_params), observed={'x': x})
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to significant help from the PyMC3 development community, I can post the
following working example of a customised Dirichlet prior in PyMC3.

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as special
import theano.tensor as tt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


n = 4

with pm.Model() as model:
    prior = np.ones(n) / n

    def dirich_logpdf(value=prior):
        return -n * special.gammaln(1/n) + (-1 + 1/n) * tt.log(value).sum()

    stick = pm.distributions.transforms.StickBreaking()
    probs = pm.DensityDist('probs', dirich_logpdf, shape=n, 
                testval=np.array(prior), transform=stick)
    data = np.array([5, 7, 1, 0])
    sfs_obs = pm.Multinomial('sfs_obs', n=np.sum(data), p=probs, observed=data)

with model:
    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(100000, tune=10000, step=step)

print('MLE = ', data / np.sum(data))
print(pm.summary(trace))

pm.traceplot(trace, [probs])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please explain why overloading pm.Dirichlet variable? specifically I am looking on a Dirichlet-like distribution that can handle matrices (all columns sum to one). Will a similar method work?

Comment: @Eran I am not sure what you mean by `overloading'. The key point with using DensityDist to customise distributions is the use of transforms. Without correct use of these, the behaviour of your RV in a model may not be what you naively expect.